# Command ">" failing in Embedded Linux only

Tags: shell, qt

I'm developing an app in Qt for Embedded Linux where I want to see how much (%) of the given partition is occupied. I found on the web that a way to do this would be by calling the `df` command passing it's results to a local file using the `>` command and then read that file with Qt:

```
system("df /home/maiquel/ > /tmp/sdcard_usage.info");
```

(don't mind the call to `system`)

I tested that in my Linux Ubuntu terminal and it worked perfectly fine. The same doesn't occur, though, in the Embedded Linux application: using the Terminal, I noticed that the `df` commands works fine, but the `>` always fails to put the results inside the file with no error messages appearing.

Any suggestions on how may I solve this problem? I found no manual for the `>` command that could help me. Notice that although the main question is about the functionality of the `>` command, any suggestion regarding the general problem I'm trying to solve is also appreciated.

Obs.: It's not a `chmod` issue since the problem also occurs when the file is with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Does your shell support pipelines (`echo foo | cat`)? Does your Linux have the command `tee`?

Comment: For the general problem, [there is this SO question about getting filesystem info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992171/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-free-disk-space-for-a-directory-in-linux). To read the output of a command if you are using Qt, use [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).

Comment: @HaukeLaging  `echo` and `cat` yes, `foo` and `tee` no. `|` I didn't test.

Comment: What value is returned by the `system()` function?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the `system` returns the correct value of `df`.

Comment: @Leiaz interestingly, I change the reading of file for QProcess and once again it worked in linux Ubuntu but not in my embedded linux system \o/ The QProcess simply doesn't receive anything (using waitFor...)

Answer (score 2):

`>` is not a command but a shell feature called redirection. This is a very basic shell feature so it seems kind of strange that a shell is supposed not to support it. Search the documentation of your shell for "redirection".